# Height won't set percent of parent

Tags: jquery, css

**Footer Container**

```
// Set Footer Size
var width = $(window).width();
var FooterHeight = width / 1.295;
$(".Footer").css({'height' : FooterHeight + 'px'});
```

**Footer Content**

```
.Footer .Content {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 52%;
    margin-left:3%;
    width:94%;
    height:48%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

**The Problem**
I am attempting using minimum code to set the content for my footer to be a percentage of the footers height and width. I have tried several methods I have sourced from StackOverflow however I believe due to JQuery setting the parents size.

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/qvj3qwjk/

**All Variable Are Correct So Should Look Like:**
[image]

Comment: Can you describe the problem using a little different words (what effect exactly you need to achieve to be satisfied)? Im not sure if i understand it properly, but regardless im almost sure it can be done without javascript/jQuery :)

Comment: Updated @Pavelloz hope this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the background image to just an img element, you do not have to use jQuery to set the footer's height. Also, if you are positioning elements absolutely, it is easier to use the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties. You can use either percents or pixel/em values for them.

Here is an example of those two in use in an example similar to yours.

```css
.Footer {
    position:relative;
}

.Footer img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.Footer .Content {
 position:absolute;
 top:52%;
 left:3%;
 right:3%;
 bottom:3%;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<!-- Footer Starts -->
<div class="Footer">
    <img src="http://rafflebananza.com/Desktop/IMG/FooterBg.png">
    <div class="Content">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer Ends -->
```

Comment: Please see [my page](http://rafflebananza.com/Desktop/index.html). The .Footer's content now appears outside of the .Footer

Comment: @TimMarshall The problem stems from not clearing your floats on the div previous to the `.Footer`. The easiest solution is to set `overflow:hidden;` on your `.MainContent`. You also don't need the jQuery which is setting the `.Footer`'s height anymore.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much @Marcelo, just got to try and remove the small gap at the bottom of the page and then I'm on track to continue! :)